# Why does Q Learning diverge?

Tags: machine-learning, python, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

My Q-Learning algorithm's state values keep on diverging to infinity, which means my weights are diverging too. I use a neural network for my value-mapping.

I've tried:

- Clipping the "reward + discount * maximum value of action" (max/min set to 50/-50)
- Setting a low learning rate (0.00001 and I use the classic Backpropagation for updating the weights)
- Decreasing the values of the rewards
- Increasing the exploration rate
- Normalizing the inputs to between 1~100 (previously it was 0~1)
- Change the discount rate
- Decrease the layers of the neural network (just for validation)

I've heard that Q Learning is known to diverge on non-linear input, but are there anything else that I can try to stop the divergence of the weights?

**Update #1 on August 14th, 2017:**

I've decided to add some specific details on what I'm doing right now due to a request to.

I'm currently trying to make an agent learn how to fight in a top-down view of a shooting game. The opponent is a simple bot which moves stochastically.

*Each character has 9 actions to choose from on each turn:*

- move up
- move down
- move left
- move right
- shoot a bullet upwards
- shoot a bullet downwards
- shoot a bullet to the left
- shoot a bullet to the right
- do nothing

*The rewards are:*

- if agent hits the bot with a bullet, +100 (I've tried many different values)
- if agent gets hit by a bullet shot by the bot, -50 (again, I've tried many different values)
- if the agent tries to fire a bullet while bullets can't be fired(ex. when the agent just fired a bullet, etc. ), -25(Not necessary but I wanted the agent to be more efficient)
- if the bot tries to go out of the arena, -20(Not necessary too but I wanted the agent to be more efficient)

*The inputs for the neural network are:*

- Distance between the agent and the bot on the X axis normalized to 0~100
- Distance between the agent and the bot on the Y axis normalized to 0~100
- Agent's x and y positions
- Bot's x and y positions
- Bot's bullet position. If the bot didn't fire a bullet, the parameters are set to the x and y positions of the bot.

I've also fiddled with the inputs too; I tried adding new features like the x value of the agent's position(not the distance but the actual position)and the position of the bot's bullet. None of them worked.

Here's the code:

```
from pygame import *
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
import random
import tensorflow as tf
from pylab import savefig
from tqdm import tqdm


#Screen Setup
disp_x, disp_y = 1000, 800
arena_x, arena_y = 1000, 800
border = 4; border_2 = 1

#Color Setup
white = (255, 255, 255); aqua= (0, 200, 200)
red = (255, 0, 0); green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255); black = (0, 0, 0)
green_yellow = (173, 255, 47); energy_blue = (125, 249, 255)

#Initialize character positions
init_character_a_state = [disp_x/2 - arena_x/2 + 50, disp_y/2 - arena_y/2 + 50]
init_character_b_state = [disp_x/2 + arena_x/2 - 50, disp_y/2 + arena_y/2 - 50]

#Setup character dimentions
character_size = 50
character_move_speed = 25

#Initialize character stats
character_init_health = 100

#initialize bullet stats
beam_damage = 10
beam_width = 10
beam_ob = -100

#The Neural Network
input_layer = tf.placeholder(shape=[1,7],dtype=tf.float32)
weight_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([7,9],0,0.1))
#weight_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([6,9],0,0.1))

#The calculations, loss function and the update model
Q = tf.matmul(input_layer, weight_1)
predict = tf.argmax(Q, 1)
next_Q = tf.placeholder(shape=[1,9],dtype=tf.float32)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(next_Q - Q))
trainer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001)
updateModel = trainer.minimize(loss)

initialize = tf.global_variables_initializer()

jList = []
rList = []

init()
font.init()
myfont = font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 15)
myfont2 = font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 150)
myfont3 = font.SysFont('Gothic', 30)
disp = display.set_mode((disp_x, disp_y), 0, 32)

#CHARACTER/BULLET PARAMETERS
agent_x = agent_y = int()
bot_x = bot_y = int()
agent_hp = bot_hp = int()
bot_beam_dir = int()
agent_beam_fire = bot_beam_fire = bool()
agent_beam_x = bot_beam_x = agent_beam_y = bot_beam_y = int()
agent_beam_size_x = agent_beam_size_y = bot_beam_size_x = bot_beam_size_y = int()
bot_current_action = agent_current_action = int()

def param_init():
    """Initializes parameters"""
    global agent_x, agent_y, bot_x, bot_y, agent_hp, bot_hp, agent_beam_fire, bot_beam_fire, agent_beam_x, bot_beam_x, agent_beam_y, bot_beam_y

    agent_x = list(init_character_a_state)[0]; agent_y = list(init_character_a_state)[1]
    bot_x = list(init_character_b_state)[0]; bot_y = list(init_character_b_state)[1]
    agent_hp = bot_hp = character_init_health
    agent_beam_fire = bot_beam_fire = False
    agent_beam_x = bot_beam_x = agent_beam_y = bot_beam_y = beam_ob
    agent_beam_size_x = agent_beam_size_y = bot_beam_size_x = bot_beam_size_y = 0


def screen_blit():
    global disp, disp_x, disp_y, arena_x, arena_y, border, border_2, character_size, agent_x, \
    agent_y, bot_x, bot_y, character_init_health, agent_hp, bot_hp, red, blue, aqua, green, black, green_yellow, energy_blue, \
    agent_beam_fire, bot_beam_fire, agent_beam_x, agent_beam_y, bot_beam_x, bot_beam_y, agent_beam_size_x, agent_beam_size_y, bot_beam_size_x, bot_beam_size_y, beam_width

    disp.fill(aqua)
    draw.rect(disp, black, (disp_x / 2 - arena_x / 2 - border, disp_y /
                            2 - arena_y / 2 - border, arena_x + border * 2, arena_y + border * 2))
    draw.rect(disp, green, (disp_x / 2 - arena_x / 2,
                            disp_y / 2 - arena_y / 2, arena_x, arena_y))
    if bot_beam_fire == True:
        draw.rect(disp, green_yellow, (agent_beam_x, agent_beam_y, agent_beam_size_x, agent_beam_size_y))
        bot_beam_fire = False
    if agent_beam_fire == True:
        draw.rect(disp, energy_blue, (bot_beam_x, bot_beam_y, bot_beam_size_x, bot_beam_size_y))
        agent_beam_fire = False

    draw.rect(disp, red, (agent_x, agent_y, character_size, character_size))
    draw.rect(disp, blue, (bot_x, bot_y, character_size, character_size))

    draw.rect(disp, red, (disp_x / 2 - 200, disp_y / 2 + arena_y / 2 +
                            border + 1, float(agent_hp) / float(character_init_health) * 100, 14))
    draw.rect(disp, blue, (disp_x / 2 + 200, disp_y / 2 + arena_y / 2 +
                            border + 1, float(bot_hp) / float(character_init_health) * 100, 14))


def bot_take_action():
    return random.randint(1, 9)

def beam_hit_detector(player):
    global agent_x, agent_y, bot_x, bot_y, agent_beam_fire, bot_beam_fire, agent_beam_x, \
    bot_beam_x, agent_beam_y, bot_beam_y, agent_beam_size_x, agent_beam_size_y, \
    bot_beam_size_x, bot_beam_size_y, bot_current_action, agent_current_action, beam_width, character_size

    if player == "bot":
        if bot_current_action == 1:
            if disp_y/2 - arena_y/2 <= agent_y <= bot_y and (agent_x < bot_beam_x + beam_width < agent_x + character_size or agent_x < bot_beam_x < agent_x + character_size):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif bot_current_action == 2:
            if bot_x <= agent_x <= disp_x/2 + arena_x/2 and (agent_y < bot_beam_y + beam_width < agent_y + character_size or agent_y < bot_beam_y < agent_y + character_size):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif bot_current_action == 3:
            if bot_y <= agent_y <= disp_y/2 + arena_y/2 and (agent_x < bot_beam_x + beam_width < agent_x + character_size or agent_x < bot_beam_x < agent_x + character_size):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif bot_current_action == 4:
            if disp_x/2 - arena_x/2 <= agent_x <= bot_x and (agent_y < bot_beam_y + beam_width < agent_y + character_size or agent_y < bot_beam_y < agent_y + character_size):
                return True
            else:
                return False
    else:
        if agent_current_action == 1:
            if disp_y/2 - arena_y/2 <= bot_y <= agent_y and (bot_x < agent_beam_x + beam_width < bot_x + character_size or bot_x < agent_beam_x < bot_x + character_size):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif agent_current_action == 2:
            if agent_x <= bot_x <= disp_x/2 + arena_x/2 and (bot_y < agent_beam_y + beam_width < bot_y + character_size or bot_y < agent_beam_y < bot_y + character_size):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif agent_current_action == 3:
            if agent_y <= bot_y <= disp_y/2 + arena_y/2 and (bot_x < agent_beam_x + beam_width < bot_x + character_size or bot_x < agent_beam_x < bot_x + character_size):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        elif bot_current_action == 4:
            if disp_x/2 - arena_x/2 <= bot_x <= agent_x and (bot_y < agent_beam_y + beam_width < bot_y + character_size or bot_y < agent_beam_y < bot_y + character_size):
                return True
            else:
                return False


def mapping(maximum, number):
    return number#int(number * maximum)

def action(agent_action, bot_action):
    global agent_x, agent_y, bot_x, bot_y, agent_hp, bot_hp, agent_beam_fire, \
    bot_beam_fire, agent_beam_x, bot_beam_x, agent_beam_y, bot_beam_y, agent_beam_size_x, \
    agent_beam_size_y, bot_beam_size_x, bot_beam_size_y, beam_width, agent_current_action, bot_current_action, character_size

    agent_current_action = agent_action; bot_current_action = bot_action
    reward = 0; cont = True; successful = False; winner = ""
    if 1 <= bot_action <= 4:
        bot_beam_fire = True
        if bot_action == 1:
            bot_beam_x = bot_x + character_size/2 - beam_width/2; bot_beam_y = disp_y/2 - arena_y/2
            bot_beam_size_x = beam_width; bot_beam_size_y = bot_y - disp_y/2 + arena_y/2
        elif bot_action == 2:
            bot_beam_x = bot_x + character_size; bot_beam_y = bot_y + character_size/2 - beam_width/2
            bot_beam_size_x = disp_x/2 + arena_x/2 - bot_x - character_size; bot_beam_size_y = beam_width
        elif bot_action == 3:
            bot_beam_x = bot_x + character_size/2 - beam_width/2; bot_beam_y = bot_y + character_size
            bot_beam_size_x = beam_width; bot_beam_size_y = disp_y/2 + arena_y/2 - bot_y - character_size
        elif bot_action == 4:
            bot_beam_x = disp_x/2 - arena_x/2; bot_beam_y = bot_y + character_size/2 - beam_width/2
            bot_beam_size_x = bot_x - disp_x/2 + arena_x/2; bot_beam_size_y = beam_width

    elif 5 <= bot_action <= 8:
        if bot_action == 5:
            bot_y -= character_move_speed
            if bot_y <= disp_y/2 - arena_y/2:
                bot_y = disp_y/2 - arena_y/2
            elif agent_y <= bot_y <= agent_y + character_size:
                bot_y = agent_y + character_size
        elif bot_action == 6:
            bot_x += character_move_speed
            if bot_x >= disp_x/2 + arena_x/2 - character_size:
                bot_x = disp_x/2 + arena_x/2 - character_size
            elif agent_x <= bot_x + character_size <= agent_x + character_size:
                bot_x = agent_x - character_size
        elif bot_action == 7:
            bot_y += character_move_speed
            if bot_y + character_size >= disp_y/2 + arena_y/2:
                bot_y = disp_y/2 + arena_y/2 - character_size
            elif agent_y <= bot_y + character_size <= agent_y + character_size:
                bot_y = agent_y - character_size
        elif bot_action == 8:
            bot_x -= character_move_speed
            if bot_x <= disp_x/2 - arena_x/2:
                bot_x = disp_x/2 - arena_x/2
            elif agent_x <= bot_x <= agent_x + character_size:
                bot_x = agent_x + character_size

    if bot_beam_fire == True:
        if beam_hit_detector("bot"):
            #print "Agent Got Hit!"
            agent_hp -= beam_damage
            reward += -50
            bot_beam_size_x = bot_beam_size_y = 0
            bot_beam_x = bot_beam_y = beam_ob
            if agent_hp <= 0:
                cont = False
                winner = "Bot"

    if 1 <= agent_action <= 4:
        agent_beam_fire = True
        if agent_action == 1:
            if agent_y > disp_y/2 - arena_y/2:
                agent_beam_x = agent_x - beam_width/2; agent_beam_y = disp_y/2 - arena_y/2
                agent_beam_size_x = beam_width; agent_beam_size_y = agent_y - disp_y/2 + arena_y/2
            else:
                reward += -25
        elif agent_action == 2:
            if agent_x + character_size < disp_x/2 + arena_x/2:
                agent_beam_x = agent_x + character_size; agent_beam_y = agent_y + character_size/2 - beam_width/2
                agent_beam_size_x = disp_x/2 + arena_x/2 - agent_x - character_size; agent_beam_size_y = beam_width
            else:
                reward += -25
        elif agent_action == 3:
            if agent_y + character_size < disp_y/2 + arena_y/2:
                agent_beam_x = agent_x + character_size/2 - beam_width/2; agent_beam_y = agent_y + character_size
                agent_beam_size_x = beam_width; agent_beam_size_y = disp_y/2 + arena_y/2 - agent_y - character_size
            else:
                reward += -25
        elif agent_action == 4:
            if agent_x > disp_x/2 - arena_x/2:
                agent_beam_x = disp_x/2 - arena_x/2; agent_beam_y = agent_y + character_size/2 - beam_width/2
                agent_beam_size_x = agent_x - disp_x/2 + arena_x/2; agent_beam_size_y = beam_width
            else:
                reward += -25

    elif 5 <= agent_action <= 8:
        if agent_action == 5:
            agent_y -= character_move_speed
            if agent_y <= disp_y/2 - arena_y/2:
                agent_y = disp_y/2 - arena_y/2
                reward += -5
            elif bot_y <= agent_y <= bot_y + character_size and bot_x <= agent_x <= bot_x + character_size:
                agent_y = bot_y + character_size
                reward += -2
        elif agent_action == 6:
            agent_x += character_move_speed
            if agent_x + character_size >= disp_x/2 + arena_x/2:
                agent_x = disp_x/2 + arena_x/2 - character_size
                reward += -5
            elif bot_x <= agent_x + character_size <= bot_x + character_size and bot_y <= agent_y <= bot_y + character_size:
                agent_x = bot_x - character_size
                reward += -2
        elif agent_action == 7:
            agent_y += character_move_speed
            if agent_y + character_size >= disp_y/2 + arena_y/2:
                agent_y = disp_y/2 + arena_y/2 - character_size
                reward += -5
            elif bot_y <= agent_y + character_size <= bot_y + character_size and bot_x <= agent_x <= bot_x + character_size:
                agent_y = bot_y - character_size
                reward += -2
        elif agent_action == 8:
            agent_x -= character_move_speed
            if agent_x <= disp_x/2 - arena_x/2:
                agent_x = disp_x/2 - arena_x/2
                reward += -5
            elif bot_x <= agent_x <= bot_x + character_size and bot_y <= agent_y <= bot_y + character_size:
                agent_x = bot_x + character_size
                reward += -2
    if agent_beam_fire == True:
        if beam_hit_detector("agent"):
            #print "Bot Got Hit!"
            bot_hp -= beam_damage
            reward += 50
            agent_beam_size_x = agent_beam_size_y = 0
            agent_beam_x = agent_beam_y = beam_ob
            if bot_hp <= 0:
                successful = True
                cont = False
                winner = "Agent"
    return reward, cont, successful, winner

def bot_beam_dir_detector():
    global bot_current_action
    if bot_current_action == 1:
        bot_beam_dir = 2
    elif bot_current_action == 2:
        bot_beam_dir = 4
    elif bot_current_action == 3:
        bot_beam_dir = 3
    elif bot_current_action == 4:
        bot_beam_dir = 1
    else:
        bot_beam_dir = 0
    return bot_beam_dir

#Parameters
y = 0.75
e = 0.3
num_episodes = 10000
batch_size = 10
complexity = 100
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(initialize)
    success = 0
    for i in tqdm(range(1, num_episodes)):
        #print "Episode #", i
        rAll = 0; d = False; c = True; j = 0
        param_init()
        samples = []
        while c == True:
            j += 1
            current_state = np.array([[mapping(complexity, float(agent_x) / float(arena_x)),
                                        mapping(complexity, float(agent_y) / float(arena_y)),
                                        mapping(complexity, float(bot_x) / float(arena_x)),
                                        mapping(complexity, float(bot_y) / float(arena_y)),
                                        #mapping(complexity, float(agent_hp) / float(character_init_health)),
                                        #mapping(complexity, float(bot_hp) / float(character_init_health)),
                                        mapping(complexity, float(agent_x - bot_x) / float(arena_x)),
                                        mapping(complexity, float(agent_y - bot_y) / float(arena_y)),
                                        bot_beam_dir
                                        ]])
            b = bot_take_action()
            if np.random.rand(1) < e or i <= 5:
                a = random.randint(0, 8)
            else:
                a, _ = sess.run([predict, Q],feed_dict={input_layer : current_state})
            r, c, d, winner = action(a + 1, b)
            bot_beam_dir = bot_beam_dir_detector()
            next_state = np.array([[mapping(complexity, float(agent_x) / float(arena_x)),
                                        mapping(complexity, float(agent_y) / float(arena_y)),
                                        mapping(complexity, float(bot_x) / float(arena_x)),
                                        mapping(complexity, float(bot_y) / float(arena_y)),
                                        #mapping(complexity, float(agent_hp) / float(character_init_health)),
                                        #mapping(complexity, float(bot_hp) / float(character_init_health)),
                                        mapping(complexity, float(agent_x - bot_x) / float(arena_x)),
                                        mapping(complexity, float(agent_y - bot_y) / float(arena_y)),
                                        bot_beam_dir
                                        ]])
            samples.append([current_state, a, r, next_state])
            if len(samples) > 10:
                for count in xrange(batch_size):
                    [batch_current_state, action_taken, reward, batch_next_state] = samples[random.randint(0, len(samples) - 1)]
                    batch_allQ = sess.run(Q, feed_dict={input_layer : batch_current_state})
                    batch_Q1 = sess.run(Q, feed_dict = {input_layer : batch_next_state})
                    batch_maxQ1 = np.max(batch_Q1)
                    batch_targetQ = batch_allQ
                    batch_targetQ[0][a] = reward + y * batch_maxQ1
                    sess.run([updateModel], feed_dict={input_layer : batch_current_state, next_Q : batch_targetQ})
            rAll += r
            screen_blit()
            if d == True:
                e = 1. / ((i / 50) + 10)
                success += 1
                break
            #print agent_hp, bot_hp
            display.update()

        jList.append(j)
        rList.append(rAll)
        print winner
```

I'm pretty sure that if you have pygame and Tensorflow and matplotlib installed in a python environment you should be able to see the animations of the bot and the agent "fighting".

I digressed in the update, but it would be awesome if somebody could also address my specific problem along with the original general problem.

Thanks!

**Update #2 on August 18, 2017:**

Based on the advice of @NeilSlater, I've implemented experience replay into my model. The algorithm has improved, but I'm going to look for more better improvement options that offer convergence.

**Update #3 on August 22, 2017:**

I've noticed that if the agent hits the bot with a bullet on a turn and the action the bot taken on that turn was not "fire a bullet", then the wrong actions would be given credit. Thus, I've turned the bullets into beams so the bot/agent takes damage on the turn the beam's fired.

Comment: Are you using experience replay and bootstrapping values from a "frozen" copy of recent network? These are approaches used in DQN - they are not guaranteed though they may be necessary for stability. Are you using a Q($\lambda$) algorithm, or just single-step Q-learning? Can you give some indication of what your environment and reward scheme is like? Single-step Q-learning will do poorly when rewards are sparse e.g. final +1 or -1 reward at end of long episode.

Comment: @NeilSlater No, I'm just using a classic single-step Q Learning. Since my code is sickeningly long I didn't add it in my question and asked a general question, but I'll add it as an update.

Comment: OK, from your update, I immediately suggest you *need* experience replay and probably also alternating networks for bootstrapping, because these are stabilising influences on reinforcement learning with non-linear approximators. I'm happy to talk through that in detail, and take a look at your project code to show an example, but might take a day or two to get back to you with that level of detail,.

Comment: I have got the code running and if I am correct in understanding it, the bullets can be "steered" by the agent selection from actions 1-4 each turn, i.e. the bullet can be moved around in any direction whilst the agent stays still. Is that intentional? The bot doesn't do this because it only fires when aligned on the grid to the agent, and always picks the same direction if it does so.

Comment: @NeilSlater Thanks, I'll look into experience replay and bootstrapping. It would be pretty awesome if you could spend the time to go into detail! Oh, and the steering was...not intentional. There must be a bug in my code; I'll  edit the code in this question once I fix it!

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Is the requirement that the agent/bot stay still whilst firing intentional? The bullet is re-set to being "inside" the agent if it takes actions 5-8, so if it fires on one timestep (e.g. action 2) and then moves (e.g. action 7), the bullet only goes one space out and then the firing state gets set to false again.

Comment: @NeilSlater Yeah, that's intentional; I wanted the bot/agents to only be able to execute one action on each turn. I've looked at experience replay, and I'm thinking how I should implement it is: I augment my state-action to value pairs to a list on every turn, and on each turn I "train"(fit the neural network) the NN with a random pair of data  from the list. Am I correct?

Comment: Almost right, but you don't store the bootstrapped value, instead re-calculate it when the step is sampled later. For each action taken, you store the four things: State, Action, Next State, Reward. Then you take a small mini-batch (1 per step is fine, but more e.g. 10 is typical) from this list and for Q-learning calculate the new max action and its value to create the supervised learning mini-batch (also called the *TD target*).

Comment: @NeilSlater I've tried experience replay, and It definitely helped! I'll try more algorithms out and see what works the best. Thanks for all the help!! And... I can't quite wrap my head around "bootstrapping on a frozen copy of the environment". Could you help me have a clearer understanding?

Comment: That should be "frozen copy of the approximator (i.e. the neural network" (if the quote is from one of my comments or answers, please point me at it and I will correct it. It's very simple - just keep two copies of the weight params $\mathbf{w}$, the "live" one that you update, and a "recent old" one that you copy from the "live" one every few hundred updates. When you calculate the TD target e.g. $R + \gamma \text{max}_{a'} \hat{q}(S',a',\mathbf{w})$ then use the "old" copy to calculate $\hat{q}$, but then train the "live" one with those values.

Comment: @NeilSlater I've tried your suggestions out, but the agent still isn't able to learn from playing the game. I'm starting to think that my choice of input features is not so good; I believe most people use the raw pixels of the environment as input data (such as Atari Breakout or Pong), while I'm using numeric values of the features of the environment such as character position. Do you think this could be a cause of the agent not converging? Thanks always for the help!

Comment: I think your features are fine, probably better than using pixel values - the acid test would be - is this data you could use to make a good decision. I am not sure what could be wrong. One thought - you have made the bot very aggressive, leaving not much room for the agent to make good decisions, perhaps tone that down a bit and see if the agent can learn in a less harsh environment. If that works, you could try ramping up the difficulty whilst exploring what changes you need to make in order for the agent to still learn.

Comment: @NeilSlater Yeah, I've tried changing the bot so that it doesn't move or shoot anything the entire time, so that the agent can have, I guess, an easier time. However, the agent still struggles on the 60th episode even though it should have learned the optimal path to win (I've seen it take the optimal actions to win around 2 to 3 times). I'm starting to think the agent isn't learning properly for some reason.

Comment: @NeilSlater Oh, and I've drastically changed the code. The bullets are beams now, due to a fatal error I noticed(description in the questions).

Comment: The bullet/beam thing should make an easier-to-learn problem for the agent, but actually should not be required. The point of learning the action value function is that the RL algorithm should figure out the relation between state/action and eventual reward even when there is a time difference between key actions and the rewards they generate. Your trouble is more likely related to how unstable and tricky neural networks are when used as estimators in Q learning. Making the problem simpler though is a reasonable plan as you explore how to get this working.

Comment: @NeilSlater I guess so... I'll try beam first, then bullets. I guess most people also go through hours of tweaking on their first or second attempts in RL, but it's really awesome to know that there's people who can help. I can't express my gratitude, and I'm absolutely certain that I'm still going to need help down the road until I get used to RL. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 6):

If your weights are diverging then your optimizer or your gradients aren't behaving well. A common reason for diverging weights is [exploding gradients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem), which can result from:

1. too many layers, or
2. too many recurrent cycles if you're using an RNN.

You can verify if you have exploding gradients as follows:

```
grad_magnitude = tf.reduce_sum([tf.reduce_sum(g**2)
                                for g in tf.gradients(loss, weights_list)])**0.5
```

Some approaches to solving the problem of exploding gradients are:

- Use [RELU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) or [ELU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)#ELUs) activations
- Use [Xavier initialization](http://andyljones.tumblr.com/post/110998971763/an-explanation-of-xavier-initialization)
- Use a [Deep Residual architecture](https://www.quora.com/How-does-deep-residual-learning-work). This will keep the gradients from being squished by subsequent layers.

Comment: Can this happen even with two hidden dense layer in a simple feedforward net?

Comment: Yes, your weights will diverge if the learning rate is too high

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a fixed point iteration to solve Bellman, it might not only be degenerate but also might have attractors at infinity or orbits. Dig into the problem you are solving and understand it deeply. Have a look at control theory. RL folks tend not to write about this as much.